# jquery.1.12.0.min.js file throwing InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character

Tags: jquery

Jquery file throwing this error but don't know why.Its working properly then suddenly this error start causing.Can anyone tell me whats the solution to this problem.
jquery.1.12.0.min.js downloaded file from jquery official site.

Comment: If you don't know what you did wrong, we certainly don't ?

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: There could be various reasons for this error, in order to drill down to the root cause kindly share more details of your code and the detailed scenario where this problem occurs